# How to enable images gallery in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to enable the function of images to show in a gallery in a post.

I have tried to just do a gallery the "normal" way in wordpress by uploading images, picking the ones I need and putting them into the post.

```
$post_id = 83;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title; ?>
<div id="gallery" class="section-top">
    <h1 class="section-heading"> <?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <p class="center-find"><?php echo $queried_post->post_content;?></p>
</div>
```

I need to be able to show the gallery on the website. When I use the shortcode from the gallery of random pics I have checked off, I can see the images in the post, BUT when I enter my website on the `front-page.php`, all I get is the actually shortcode displayed and no images.

If I open the post as a "view post", the gallery is displayed, so I imagine that I am missing something in my code to get the images on the front page.

If I use the short code directly in `front-page.php`, I get the gallery as well, but then my users can't make the gallery like they want it to look like and would have to manually edit the template files themselves and they know nothing about coding.

Comment: do_shortcode($queried_post->post_content);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply a filter to the post content if you want it to pass the shortcode.  You might also want to use get_the_title instead of the post object.

```
$post_id = 83;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $queried_post->post_content );
$title = get_the_title($post_id);
 <div id="gallery" class="section-top">
   <h1 class="section-heading"> <?php echo $title; ?></h1>
   <p class="center-find"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll test it out tonight :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Is there any other suggestions you can bring that i should include in this specific code? or another way to control what content gets put where ? Any suggestions is appreciated.